# drupal_render() and drupal_get_form()

Tags: 7, forms

In the following snippet, the form returned has only the hidden values. No name, email, or comment.

```
require_once drupal_get_path('module', 'contact') .'/contact.pages.inc';
$elements = drupal_get_form(array('contact_site_form'));
$form = drupal_render($elements);
```

Can anyone say why `$form` is not returning an HTML form?

Comment: Maybe because drupal_get_form returns an html representation of whatever form is passed in the argument.

Comment: I meant to ask, why is this NOT returning a html string? (oops, my cred is falling faster than some presidential candidates!)

Comment: Are you using D7 or D6?

Comment: This is Drupal 7, and it suddenly started working. Weird ass Drupal (-;

Comment: @stefgosselin drupal_get_form does not return html, it returns the form array.

Comment: Oh, not sure but maybe some data was 'cached', I mean had you tried drush cc all to clear your cache?  when playing in rendering functions I think sometimes stuff in there is cached and running cc all empties the registry among other things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
drupal_get_form('contact_site_form');
```